# Theme not applied to Applications

Tags: themes, gnome-tweaks

I just applied Orchis Theme to my Ubuntu. I don't find Application drop-down in Tweaks -> Appearance instead there is Legacy Applications now.
But theme on Legacy Application is not working on Applications like Firefox or Files etc.

Comment: Hi, do you have installed package `gnome-tweaks`? If so look for an option related to applying the theme to applications or legacy applications. Is there?

Comment: Yes, I have gnome-tweaks installed already. Answer of @Nic helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox (deb), Gnome Settings and Files (Nautilus) are following since Gnome 42 the GTK4/libadwaita styling. You didn't state with Ubuntu Version you're using, so I assume you use the current LTS version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS).

You have to install the Orchis Theme using the `-l / --libadwaita`-argument, so `./install.sh -l` and your other arguments.

To install the Dark Mode for the Settings you also have to add the argument `-c dark`, so `./install.sh -c dark -l`. After that it should work.

But the snap version of Firefox (which is installed by default) and Chromium also lacks GTK3-styling so you have two options to go with firefox: (**You only have to use one of the following options**)

1. ### Install the DEB-Version of Firefox

   1. Uninstall the Snap-Version of Firefox: `sudo snap remove firefox`
   2. Add the official Mozilla-PPA: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa`
   3. Change the APT-Settings to prioritize the firefox DEB-version:

   ```
   echo '
   Package: *
   Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
   Pin-Priority: 1001
   ' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox
   ```

   and

   ```
   echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox
   ```

   4. Install firefox using APT: `sudo apt install firefox`
2. ### Search for an Orchis-Firefox theme

I hope I could help you.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the post. I followed your all steps and theme is applied on other apps.
Again Thank you for your time.